# Groovy: Variable Substitution in dynamic Strings

Tags: groovy, templates

I'm currently facing a variable substitution related problem in groovy. While this is quite trivial:

```
Map map = [s1:"Hello", s2:"World"]
println "${map.s1} ${map.s2}!" // "Hello World!"
```

As this works, I'm pretty sure that something like this should work as well:

```
Map map = [s1:"Hello", s2:"World"]
def dynamic = loadStringFromFile();

println "${dynamic} ${dynamic.class}" // "${s1} ${s2}! (java.lang.String)"

// now the voodoo part
println applyVoodoo(dynamic, map) // "Hello World!"
```

Does anybody know how to get this working?

Cheers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would normally do this with [Groovy Templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html).

Answer (score 7):

```
dynamic.replaceAll(/\$\{(\w+)\}/) { m, k -> map[k] }
```

Comment: This works, thanks!

However, as I was looking for something that's closer to using static strings, I came up with another solution:

def applyVoodoo(String str, Map map) {
 Binding b = new Binding();
 for (e in map) b.setVariable(e.key, e.value);
 GroovyShell sh = new GroovyShell(b);
 return sh.evaluate("\"${str}\"");
}

Comment: re: Binding. This is a good approach and a very powerful tool. Note that you can pass the map in to the Binding constructor (for 1.6.4 at least).

Comment: incredibly powerful and elegant

Answer (score 3):

For a similar but more general problem, I tried using SimpleTemplateEngine, but found it frustrating in that you can't avoid getting MissingPropertyException whenever a placeholder is not found in your map.
I ended up using this generalized variation of sepp2k's answer:

```
def s = '${s1} ${s2} $s{3}' // single quotes!
result = s.replaceAll(/\$\{(\w+)\}/) { k -> m[k[1]] ?: k[0] }
println result
```

which gives what *I* wanted:

```
"Hello World $s{3}"
```

The this works because the `replaceAll(/group/ { k ->` fills `k` with an array: the first element is the full match, and the 2nd is the group. So in my case where the pattern is (sans escape chars) `${(+w)}` then `k[0]` is the whole match: `"${s1}"` and `k[1]` the group match `"s1"`, so

```
map[k[1]] = map["s1"] = "Hello"
```

and if `map[k1]` is `null` I use elvis `?:` to sub in the full `k0` which is the un-expanded variable, like `${s3}`

Answer (score 3):

This would do it:

```java
Map map = [s1:"Hello", s2:"World"]
String dynamic = '${s1} ${s2}!' // Plain string, can be loaded from a file

// Voodoo part
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(new Binding(map))
println shell.evaluate('"' + dynamic +'"')  // Hello World!
```

When the `dynamic` string is wrapped with double quotes, it evaluates to `GString` with variable interpolation. This means, we have all the flexibility of variable references, without complexity of Groovy Templates.

If we can accept slight modification on variable references, we have even simpler options:

```java
Map map = [s1:"Hello", s2:"World"]
String dynamic = '${x.s1} ${x.s2}!'  // Plain string

// The voodoo part
println Eval.x(map, '"' + dynamic +'"')  // Hello World!

// This way, we can also access the map methods
dynamic = 'values: ${x.values()}'
println Eval.x(map, '"' + dynamic +'"')  // values: [Hello, World]
```

Comment: Now that is pure voodoo. Sadly I  can't do this on the team jenkins server due to access exceptions :(